# --enable-pic equivalent in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

What setting in Visual Studio C++ project, would be equivalent to *nix `--enable-pic` switch, i.e. `./configure --enable-pic`

Comment: It might be better to describe what you want to achieve rather than the `./configure` option.  Then you'll get a greater set of people able to answer.

Comment: I wanted to build a project for which `--enable-pic` was suggested (on *nix environment)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is none since it is not required.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code:
"Microsoft Windows DLLs are not shared libraries in the Unix sense and do not use position independent code"

Comment: It seems that quotation no longer exists in that link.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library

"Windows does not use position-independent code for its DLLs; instead the code undergoes relocation as it is loaded, fixing addresses for all its entry points at locations which are free in the memory space of the first process to load the DLL."