# Using a compiler other than cl.exe in Windows 10 to compile .cu files with nvcc

Tags: gcc, cuda, nvcc

I am trying to use GCC to compile with nvcc as opposed to cl.exe using the command

```
nvcc -c -o depthconv_cuda_kernel.o depthconv_cuda_kernel.cu --compiler-bindir "C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin" --allow-unsupported-compiler  -x cu -Xcompiler -fPIC -std c++11 --gpu-architecture=compute_86 --gpu-code=sm_86 -DGPU -I"C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.1/include" -DCUDNN --compiler-options "-DGPU -DCUDNN -fPIC"
```

Importantly I have set --compiler-bindir to the mingw bin directory, as well
as used the flag --allow-unsupported-compiler (not sure if that is necessary).

I need gcc for the command line options std c++11 as well as -fPIC . It seems nvcc is still looking for MSVC's cl.exe, how can I change this so it uses the GCC compiler I need? I get the message:

Failed to run C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/cl.exe (The system cannot find the file specified.
).
nvcc fatal   : Failed to preprocess host compiler properties.

Comment: The only supported host compiler for CUDA on windows is cl.exe

Comment: @RobertCrovella I was afraid that might be the case, but I wanted to make sure. Is there any way around this, i.e to adapt the flags I need for cl.exe, in particular -fPIC and support for c++ 11 ?

Comment: I don't know if there is any way to trick nvcc. There was at least one question on the cuda tag where people were discussing how to use mingw. If you search on the cuda tag for mingw you may find it. Good luck!

Comment: any recent version of cl.exe supports c++11 natively.  You don't need a flag for that.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/13309662/681865 -- I get the strong feel you don't understand what you are asking for and why you are asking for it

Comment: @talonmies I just read this, and yes you are right, I am new to some of these topics. It seems that asking for -fPIC doesn't really make sense in the context of windows if I understand correctly. Any other thoughts/reading material appreciated as I am just learning.